# How do I connect a VGA input to my PC so that it shows up as a video device?

Tags: vga, video-capture

This is the Windows/PC counter part of [this question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48479/7833)
I want to clarify that I am *not* talking about connecting a VGA monitor to a computer. I'm referring to plugging in a VGA output in to my computer. I want the VGA feed to show up as a video device, so that I can run a projector's feed through UStream and be able to switch between that feed and the camera that I am using. The computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad.

What hardware is needed to digitize a VGA input in real time to send for broadcast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need (for both mac and PC) is a [VGA Capture Card](https://www.google.com/search?q=vga%20capture%20card) or also known as a Frame Grabber. High end ones that can do 30fps+ at 1920x1200 are not cheap ($800+) but if you are willing to go to a lower resolution or be willing to do lower fps it can bring the price down a lot.

---

If you can get a signal like HDMI or Component from your projector it actually [gets a lot cheaper](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007683%20600049972&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Order=PRICE&PageSize=20) as the market for buying those type of devices is a lot bigger.

Comment: Thanks so much, Scott! I was actually just looking at those frame grabbers from Epiphan. I'm will wait a couple days for more answers, then accept yours.

Comment: Check the new-egg link, it is always smart to shop around as sometimes the most expensive thing is not always the best thing.

Comment: I absolutely will! Thank you so much of your help! Side question: can I take a VGA feed, convert it to HDMI, then run it to an HDMI to USB cable?

Comment: Yes but the cost of the VGA to HDMI converter + hdmi capture card may be more than just the cost of the VGA conveter alone.

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. I just wanted to make sure it was actually possible. :-) Thanks again!